# Coloring python shapes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get this figure to change colors along the way but I'm not sure what I did wrong. Only black lines are drawn, the code is as follows:

```
import turtle

colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"]
NUM_LINES = 100

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"]

for x in range(NUM_LINES):
  color = colors[x%4]
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(2+(4*x))

  for color in ['red', 'blue', 'brown', 'black']:

        turtle.pencolor(color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop changes the pen color from red, to blue, to brown, to black, and *then* goes to the next line drawing step of the outer loop. So only black lines get drawn. Your `color = colors[x%4]` logic is fine, so use that instead:

```
for x in range(NUM_LINES):
  color = colors[x%4]
  turtle.pencolor(color)
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(2+(4*x))
```

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that the first time. Hell I didn't even notice the colors in my loop were different compared to what colors =  was.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance though, it worked out in the end. I didn't need the colors per say but I figured it would have looked better and easier t see then just a big ol generic black hypno pattern

Answer (score 0):

Or do the below, have another style of colors:

```
for x in range(NUM_LINES):
  color = colors[x//25]
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(2+(4*x))
  turtle.pencolor(color)
```

---

```
import turtle

colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"]
NUM_LINES = 100

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"]


for x in range(NUM_LINES):
  color = colors[x//25]
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(2+(4*x))
  turtle.pencolor(color)
```

End of the process of output:

[image]